# How to customize node js lib and include it in project

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to override some scripts in downloadable library, but it so big that I can't include it in source code of project. Is it a good practice in node js to customize npm library and include it into main project. How to specify it lib in project?

Comment: What you mean saying "specify it lib"?